# Using Substring in Nhibernate to SQL

Tags: sql, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I am trying to find the prefixes of my account names so I can use them in a filter in my UI.

However whenever I execute the following linq statement it always brings back the whole account name and then performs the substring. Instead of writing the sql equivalent.

```
return this.Accounts(user).Select(x => x.Name.Substring(0, 1)).ToList().Distinct();
```

this.Accounts is IQueryable so it should not force a callback to the database.

Is there any reason why it would return them all and then substring the resulting names or is there a working alternative?

**Edit**

```
private IQueryable<Account> Accounts(User user)
{
  var accounts = this.SessionManager.GetActiveSession().Query<Account>().Where(x => x.Company.Id == user.Company.Id);
  if (!user.IsAdmin && user.AccountProfiles.Any())
  {
    accounts = accounts.Where(x => x.AssociatedProfiles.Any(y => y.Users.Any(z => z.Id == user.Id)));
  }

  return accounts;
}
```

Comment: Please show how you are declaring and obtaining `this.Accounts`.

Comment: The declaration of `this.Accounts` is still missing. The behavior you described would be consistent with that property being declared as `IEnumerable<Account>`.

Comment: this.Accounts() is a function within the same class as the original code, and is private because it does not have a signature declaration. Am I misinterpreting you?

Comment: My bad, I misread part of it. Let me do a reproduction and I'll come back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a simple `Account` class containing only a `string Name` property.

Your first block, performed on `session.Query<Account>()` results in the SQL one would expect:

```
select
    substring(account0_.Name,
    @p0+1,
    @p1) as col_0_0_
from
    Account account0_;
@p0 = 0 [Type: Int32 (0)],
@p1 = 1 [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

It's worth noting that `Distinct()` was left *after* the `ToList()` call. Otherwise, you'd get something better:

```
select
    distinct substring(account0_.Name,
    @p0+1,
    @p1) as col_0_0_
from
    Account account0_;
@p0 = 0 [Type: Int32 (0)],
@p1 = 1 [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

My suggestion is that you reduce the `Accounts(User)` method to a single statement:

```
return SessionManager.GetActiveSession().Query<Account>();
```

...And start adding the rest of it until it fails.

Side note: all tests done using the latest NHibernate stable release (3.3.0 as of now)

Comment: The reason I was using Distinct after ToList (although it is better the other way around) is because it throws an __Expression type 'NhDistinctExpression' is not supported by this SelectClauseVisitor.__ error when I do.

Comment: ``return this.SessionManager.GetActiveSession().Query<Account>().Select(x => x.Name.Substring(1, 1))`` produces the following Sql ``select account0_.Name as col_0_0_
from   [Client].[dbo].Account account0_``

Comment: Am now trying this and the substring function is working, but the distinct is not being applied ``var q = this.SessionManager.GetActiveSession().QueryOver<Account>().Select(x => x.Name.Substr(1, 1)).TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity);``

Comment: Fixed by projecting an sql function. ``var q =
        this.SessionManager.GetActiveSession().QueryOver<Account>().Select(
          Projections.Distinct(Projections.SqlFunction("substring", NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property("Name"),
                                                       Projections.Constant(1), Projections.Constant(1))));``